# save data to excel using openpyxl

Tags: python

I use the code fragment below to copy data to an excel file using openpyxl.

```
      for i, j in enumerate(fint):
       _= ws1.cell(column=i +1, row=globdat.cycle, value=j)

   wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

BUT

after doing so I have found the code to become very slow. is there a better way of doing this ?

globdat.cycle is a count for each iteration.

'fint' is a row vector with an unknown number of entries in each iteration.

Nb- I am working with large amounts of data so only openpyxl seem to work.